# Deleting masked elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have some arrays that contain masked elements (from `Numpy.MaskedArray`), e.g.

```
data = [0,1,masked,3,masked,5,...]
```

Where the mask doesn't follow a regular pattern.

I want to iterate through the array and simply delete all elements that are masked to end up with:

```
data = [0,1,3,5,...]
```

I've tried a loop like:

```
for i in xrange(len(data)):
    if np.ma.is_masked(data[i]):
        data.pop(i)
```

But I get the error: `local variable 'data' referenced before assignment`

Do I have to create a new array and add the unmasked elements? Or is there a `MaskedArray` function that can automatically do this? I've had a look at the documentation but it's not obvious to me.

Thanks!

Comment: What is mask actually? Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Your error is unrelated to your problem

Comment: [x for x in data if isinstance(x,(int))] ?

Comment: @JejeBelfort this just returned the original list

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With mask *bitwise invertion* `~`:

```
data = data[~data.mask]
```

Comment: I get the error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mask'`

Comment: @RichardHall, but you have wrote that you have masked numpy array

Comment: Actually I found it, I converted my masked elements to NaNs and didn't see, so I was getting these errors. Your solution worked when I removed that, thanks :)

Comment: Note that unlike my solution, this returns a masked array, not a normal array

Comment: should you return data[~data.mask].data? Otherwise it is still masked array with all performance overheads.

Comment: @Vlad and Eric, can you describe how you determined that they were different array types? New users may not know how to inspect objects for extra attributes.

`np.array_equal(data.compressed(), data[~data.mask])` resolved to `True`.

Answer (score 18):

[`data.compressed()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.compressed.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.compressed) is the function you're looking for

Comment: This doesn't work, I get the  `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'compress'` error

Comment: @RichardHall Based on this error, it looks like you may have typed the function name incorrectly. @Eric's solution says `compressed` and your error says `compress`.

Comment: @emem_tee, it also looks like `data` was a `list`, and not a numpy masked array (`numpy.ma.MaskedArray`).